# Changing viewControllers with ECSlidingView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have a view that contains a ECSlidingView:
[image: The view, containing a slider (appears on the left when clicking the hamburger icon)]

Bij clicking the '+' button, you enter another view, without the ECSlidingView:

[image: Second view]

Now, I would like to return to the first view once a user clicks on the 'Voeg Toe' button in the second view. I have tried using:

```
FoodViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Voedingsdagboek"];
    [self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, now the ECSlider does not work anymore. So I cannot navigate through the rest of the application. How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you currently showing the `Voeg item` viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I fixed it by using:

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Voedingsdagboek"];
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

To go back to previous view you can write `popViewController` in `buttonTapped` Method.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```